# Working with foreach, issets, arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

What is the best practise to move for multiple foreach statements to an array? I am repeating the process in my code, when I know there is a better and faster way to do this. Is it possible to `isset` the `foreach`? I am starting to work with `PDO`, how would I shorten my below code or move it into an array of some type?

```
if (isset($_POST['one'], $_POST['two'], $_POST['three'])) {

    foreach($_POST['one'] as $id => $one) {
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET one = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($one, $id)); 
    } 

    foreach($_POST['two'] as $id => $two) {
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET two = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($two, $id)); 
    }  

    foreach($_POST['three'] as $id => $three) {
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET three = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($three, $id)); 
    } 
}
```

EDIT: An example of the HTML/PHP (input type='text') for a more clear example:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo " 
<input type='text' id='one' value='{$row['one']}' name = 'one[{$row['id']}]' />
<input type='text' id='two' value='{$row['two']}' name = 'two[{$row['id']}]' />
<input type='text' id='three' value='{$row['three']}' name = 'three[{$row['id']}]' />";
}
```

Comment: what does the structure of your $_POSTs look like? seems like you could optimise the HTML end first, because this looks a little strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all the inputs will have the same IDs:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table set one = :one, two = :two, three = :three where id = :id";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(':one', $one);
$q->bindParam(':two', $two);
$q->bindParam(':three', $three);
$q->bindParam(':id', $id);
foreach ($_POST['one'] as $id => $one) {
    $two = $_POST['two'][$id];
    $three = $_POST['three'][$id];
    $q->execute();
}
```

You should only prepare the statement once, not every time through the loop. And by using `bindParam` you can bind all the parameters to variable references. You can then set all the variables in one loop, and execute the query with those values.

Comment: Legend. You my friend, should be knighted! I wouldn't expect anything less from a fellow bearded man!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
<?PHP
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if(isset($name,$value)){
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET $name = $value WHERE id = $name";
        $q->execute($db->prepare($sql)); 
    }
}
?>
```

If you're posting other information too, you can move this into an array. Then have

```
foreach($_POST[fieldsToUpdate] as $name => $value) {
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The more I read it, the more it amazes me. But most of all it makes me wonder, who would upvote it.

Comment: The question was not how to make it secure, but how to loop faster through the POST inputs. I'm assuming that the inputs are cleaned and secured properly either right after the POST occurs, or before inserting into DB.